# Set max constraint width to compose widget placed between other fix sized widgets

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a layout like on the scheme below:

[image]

I've already found a solution with a weighted `Row()` inside other `Row()`. But it looks too complicated for such a simple problem.

```
Row() {
    Icon()                                    // Fix width
    Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))  // Max width
        Icon()                                // Fix width
    }
}
```

Surely many have faced such an issue. Are there more beautiful ways to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not use a nested Row here. Just give the `weight(1f)` modifier to center element.

```kotlin
Row {
    Icon() // View 1 (Fix width)
    CenterPiece(
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)  // For the spacing between components
    )
    Icon() // View 3 (Fix width)                               
}
```

You might also want to add `verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically` to the `Row` so that the three components are centered vertically.

Comment: It really works, thx! (alignment was omitted here for simplification of the code snippet)